# Can I have more than one submit that almost does the same action?

Tags: coldfusion

I have a form that is submitted, it show all the comments from a table 
which are showing properly and able to submit good.
I would like to add ( if possible ) a submit button for EVERY comment that 
display. In the original code below it has one submit button, so when a user 
click on it it will submit all comments.
I would like it to be a option to have 'submit all' button and 
'submit' individual comment, if this is possible?

What would be the best way to approced this?

```
<form method="post" action="cse_execoffice_pending.cfm" name="review_comments">
<cfoutput>
<input type="hidden" name="txtApprovedBy" value="#GetCurrentUser.emp_id#">
<input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#Mush2.Recordcount#">
</cfoutput>
<cfoutput query="Mush3">
    <hr>
        <div class="comments_approvaldecision">
            <p>
            <input type="hidden" name="txtResponseID#CurrentRow#" value="#response_id#">
            <input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#CurrentRow#" id="approve#CurrentRow#" value="1" checked="checked"> <label for="approve#CurrentRow#">Approve</label><br>
            <input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#CurrentRow#" id="deny#CurrentRow#" value="2"> <label for="deny#CurrentRow#">Deny</label>
            </p>
        </div>

        <div class="comments_pendingapproval">

        <div class="clearfloat<cfif (#commentpositive# eq '')> hideempty</cfif>"> Positive Comments:<br>
        <cfset reReplaceCommentpositive = reReplace(commentpositive, '<br>', '', 'ALL')>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentPositive#CurrentRow#">#reReplaceCommentpositive#</textarea></div>
        <div class="clearfloat<cfif (#commentnegative# eq '')> hideempty</cfif>"> Negative Comments:<br>
        <cfset reReplaceCommentnegative = reReplace(commentnegative, '<br>', '', 'ALL')>
        <textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentNegative#CurrentRow#">#reReplaceCommentnegative#</textarea></div>


        <table>
        <thead><tr><th>Rating</th><th>Question</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody>
        <cfloop index="i" from="1" to="5">
        <cfset rating = Mush3["rating" & i][Mush3.CurrentRow]>
        <cfset question = Mush3["csedept_question" & i][Mush3.CurrentRow]>
            <tr>
                <td valign="top">
                    <cfif #rating# eq 5></cfif>
                    ........more code ...
                </td>
                <td valign="top">#question#</td>
            </tr>
        </cfloop>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    </div>
</cfoutput>

<p><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can...Here is a simple example of using buttons to do different things (in the same form).

```
<cfif form.action is "insert">
    <!---Insert code here....--->
</cfif>
<cfif form.action eq "update">
    <!---update code here--->
</cfif>
<cfif form.action eq "delete">
    <!---delete code here--->
</cfif>
<form action="">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="insert">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="update">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="delete">
</form>
```

**More:**

You asked if you can submit a record without spinning through all the others. Right?

In that case you need to wrap your cfoutput tag around your form.  You will spawn many forms. Notice that I have a unique name for each form when I loop over the recurs using your currentrow as a unique-ifyer :) I rendered your form to a basic example so you can see without all that other stuff...

```
<cfoutput query="Mush3">
<form method="post" action="" name="comments#CurrentRow#">
<input type="hidden" name="txtApprovedBy" value="#GetCurrentUser.emp_id#">
<input type="hidden" name="txtTotalRecords" value="#Mush2.Recordcount#">
<input type="hidden" name="txtResponseID#CurrentRow#" value="#response_id#">
Approve or Deny:<br>
<label for="approve#CurrentRow#">
<input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#CurrentRow#" id="approve#CurrentRow#" value="1" checked="checked">Approve</label> 
<label for="deny#CurrentRow#">
<input type="radio" name="execoffice_status#CurrentRow#" id="deny#CurrentRow#" value="2">Deny</label> 
<br>
Positive comment:<br>
<textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentPositive#CurrentRow#">#reReplaceCommentpositive#</textarea></div>
<br>
Negative comment:<br>
<textarea rows="3" name="txtCommentNegative#CurrentRow#">#reReplaceCommentnegative#</textarea></div>
<br>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</cfoutput>
```

If you take this basic example.  Add a

```
<cfdump var="#form#">
```

You will see you have a unique set of form data for only one form / currentrow.

And I believe that is what you are looking for, yes?

Comment: i see but can it be done for each individual comment, like it will be submitter for each comment or submit all

Comment: @yes i was asking if i could add a record without spinning through all the others, and it the end have a submit that you can submit them all

Comment: with all the changes , gives me erros

Comment: Refactoring code is not fun. I assume the code that processes the form is expecting something different than what you are feeding it? I would approach the problem like this. Get your cfoutput loop to spawn the individual forms in a new page. Inspect the form and determine if all the variables look correct (view the clientside source). Populating properly? Then make a new form processing page that matches the data you are trying to submit. If you can create a new question with your new form and form process code fresh eyes can make suggestions.